# How to select feature sizes

Tags: python, numpy, feature-extraction, feature-selection

im trying to replicate an experiment on a paper using SVM, to increment my learning/knownledge on machine learning. In this paper, the author extracts the features and chooses the feature sizes. He, then shows a table where F represents the size of the feature vector and N represents the face images

[image]

He then works with F >= 9 and N >= 15 parameters.

Now, what i want to do is to actually grab the features i extract as he does in the paper.

Basically, this is how i extract the features:

```
def load_image_files(fullpath, dimension=(64, 64)):
    descr = "A image classification dataset"
    images = []
    flat_data = []
    target = []
    dimension=(64, 64)
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
        for person in os.listdir(path):
            personfolder = os.path.join(path, person)
            for imgname in os.listdir(personfolder):
                class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
                fullpath = os.path.join(personfolder, imgname)
                img_resized = resize(skimage.io.imread(fullpath), dimension, anti_aliasing=True, mode='reflect')
                flat_data.append(img_resized.flatten())
                images.append(skimage.io.imread(fullpath))
                target.append(class_num)

    flat_data = np.array(flat_data)
    target = np.array(target)
    images = np.array(images)
    print(CATEGORIES)

    return Bunch(data=flat_data,
                     target=target,
                     target_names=category,
                     images=images,
                     DESCR=descr)
```

How do i select the amount of features extracted and stored? or how do i manually store a vector with the amount of features that i need? For instance a feature vector of size 9

I'm trying to separate my features this way:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    image_dataset.data, image_dataset.target, test_size=0.3,random_state=109)

model = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=10)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(model.feature_importances_)
```

Though, my output is:

[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]

for SVM classification, im trying to use OneVsRestClassifier

```
model_to_set = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel="poly"))

parameters = {
    "estimator__C": [1,2,4,8],
    "estimator__kernel": ["poly", "rbf"],
    "estimator__degree":[1, 2, 3, 4],
}

model_tunning = GridSearchCV(model_to_set, param_grid=parameters)
model_tunning

model_tunning.fit(X_train, y_train)

prediction = model_tunning.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)
```

Then, once i call prediction, i get:

```
Out[29]:
array([1, 0, 4, 2, 1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 4, 2,
       2, 4])
```

Comment: Could you provide the structure of `target` - that's where your features currently reside. Without a sense of what the individual elements are, suggesting a concrete solution is challenging

Comment: I edited the question with my fuction that i use to extract the features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've got two arrays of image information (one unprocessed, the other resized and flattened) as well as a list of corresponding class values (which we usually call labels). There are currently 2 things not quite right with the setup, however:

1) What's missing here are multiple `features` - these might include specific arrays from data associated with feature extraction from morphological/computer vision processes of your images, or they may be ancillary data like a list of preferences, behaviors, purchases. Basically, anything that can act as an array in either a numerical or categorical format. Technically speaking, your resized images are a second feature, but I don't think this will add much if any improvement in model performance.

2) `target_names=category` in your function return will store the last iteration pf category in CATEGORIES. I don't know if this is what you want.

---

Going back to your table, N would refer to the number of images in the dataset, and F would be the number of corresponding feature arrays associated with that image. By way of example, let's say we have fifty individual wines and five features (colour, taste, alcohol content, pH, optical density). N of 5 would be five of those wines, and F of 2 would be, say, `colour, taste`.

If I had to guess at what your features would be, they would in fact be a single feature - the image data itself. Looking at your data structure, every label/category you have will have multiple individuals (people) each with multiple examples of images of that person. Note that multiple individuals are not separate features - the way you're structuring the data, the individuals are grouped together under a single category.

So, where to from here? Without knowing what paper you're reading it's hard to suggest what to do, but I would go back and see if you can perhaps provide us with more information about the problem.

Comment: The article name is thermal face recognition based on physiological information by Dong, National. As for the category, i have 5 folders that are categories and each folder has 20 people and each people has many pictures, i can't really tell if its really showing me the last iteration. As for the features, whats a good way to seperate them in rows and columns? Given that, i have to fit them later in SVM

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to access the paper through my university library or locate a free version, apologies.

Comment: What we're still missing is a clear idea of what the features/labels are. Is your SVM trying to train to find an individual's ID (20 folders) given a photo, or if a given photo belongs to a category (5 labels). Are all the 20 subfolders in each category of the same person i.e. is subfolder [1] in every category folder always the same person? If so, then your labels are actually one of the 20 subfolder IDs, and the features are actually the 'category'. Once you know what you want, then we can suggest separation of data into labels/features for SVM training

Comment: Well, my labels are actually the categories. As for what exactly are the features, thats actually what i want to figure out. What i wanna do is get the feature vector in different sizes and measure them for different recognition rates. Though, exactly do i extract a feature vector with N size of my choice?

Comment: Question, could i use dimension reduction methods to select the size of my feature vector?

Comment: That's an interesting idea. You could probably use something like a PCA for that, but the end result will be a component - a representation of your features - rather than distinct features themselves. I think the paper you are following deals with distinct features so the results will be different.

Comment: target_names=category in your function return will store the last iteration pf category in CATEGORIES. I don't know if this is what you want. @PeptideWtich, no it isn't how do i store all categories?

Comment: I think for that one you probably just want `CATEGORIES`, which I'm guessing is a list of all the cats you want